# Adding Browser History and Navigation To JavaScript DOM Page Change Function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser-history

I am using JavaScript to change the pages of my website, but I am running into the issue where I can't use browser navigation to go back or forwards through the history once I have changed pages.

I have tried adding a `/#pagename` to the URL for each page, and a few other things, but I can't seem to find something that works.  I need to be able to make sure that the browser is saving the history of the page changes I make, so it can navigate those pages with the forward and back buttons.

```
// Change Page Function

function ChangeContent (page) {

var pages={"homepage":{title: "homepage"},"servicespage":{title: "servicespage"}};


//Show home page
for(var homepage in pages) {

    if(page!==homepage) {

        document.getElementById(homepage).style.display='none';
    }

    else {

        document.getElementById(homepage).style.display='block';
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
}

//Show services page
for(var servicespage in pages) {

    if(page!==servicespage) {

        document.getElementById(servicespage).style.display='none';
    }

    else {

        document.getElementById(servicespage).style.display='block';
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [`window.history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState()_method) to add history entries and [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) to react to the user travelling "backward" through the entries you've added.

When you want to "change" pages, make a call like:

```
window.history.pushState( stateData, title, url );
```

where...

- `stateData` is some object containing data you define
- `title` is a string name for the new state
- `url` is the string to which the browser's url should be changed

For example, if you want to change to "servicespage" and make the url change to "/#services":

```
window.history.pushState( { title: "Services" }, "servicespage", "/#services" );
```

Note that you still have to manipulate the DOM at this point.

Then, if you want to react to the user going backward through history:

```
window.onpopstate = function( event ) {
  var data = event.state;

  // data references the first argument of 'pushState'
  // do whatever showing or hiding of <div>s here
};
```

Comment: Good advice, definitely on the right track; I've been trying to figure out how to make `pushState` and `onpopstate` work together for a while now. I get the concept of pushing a state to the history, and that `onpopstate` fires a function when the history is manipulated, but say the `data` state I am going back to is `homepage`, how would I make the `onpopstate` function display that specific state?

Comment: Whatever data you passed to `pushState` will be stored in `event.state`, where `event` is the first argument passed to whatever callback you give to `onpopstate`. By this, you decide what data gets passed back and forth between states and your callbacks, but it is still up to you to update the document accordingly. For example, if you make a `pushState` call with `{ pageName: "homepage" }`, then when the user navigates back through that state your callbacks will be given that object. But, no other changes will occur to the document; you must do these yourself.